# Dynamically Centre Align an Input Text Field in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have used a TextFormField() in my app for inserting an amount of money one can withdraw by inserting the number. But the issue after inserting the amount in the box the inputted text is not getting dynamically centred with reference to the box. I wanted to centre the inputted text dynamically like the one which is present in the Google Pay application. I have hereby attached the photo of the Gpay App like which I want it in my app.

Gpay Amount Entering Screen

[image]

Below I have attached my code and the image of my application where i am facing the issue of alignment.
`

```
Center(
                child: Container(
                  height: 124,
                  width: 224,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: formInputFieldBortderColor,
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 82),
                        child: SvgPicture.asset(AssetRewards.rupees),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: TextFormField(
                          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                          maxLength: 3,
                          controller: _textControllor,
                          cursorColor: individualDateColor,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                          ],
                          style: GoogleFonts.mulish(
                            color: activeTextColor,
                            fontSize: 44,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            letterSpacing: 2,
                          ),
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            hintText: "0",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: textLightColor),
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            counterText: "",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

`
I have used this in my application but it doesn't makes the inputted text dynamically centre.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you are not able to set text in center cause of you rupees image dont give static padding to your image try to adjust it and give your TextFormField textAlign value center.

```
 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
```